# Replacement needed by using replaceAll method

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I would like to get replaced string however I am unable to resolve which regex should be used.

Firstly I have many string like that;

```
String rawString = "w1.28-user_request"
```

Then , I want to get the string like that;

`w1_28-user_request`

As I said that, I have some string like that; `week1.detailed_design` so in that case I will have `week1_detailed_design`. Finally I just need to handle the case that `w1.23_design_req-open`

PS: user,request etc. are just a sample naming object

Please consider that, below usage is not useful for me because I have already had `"."` other than above case. For instance;

`user.request_updated`

So I just need to know how can I handle the case for this: `w2.25-update_request`

```
rawString.replaceAll("\\.","_"); // not useful
```

Finally, patterns are below;

- *string1.2string* should be *string1_2string*
- *1.2string* should be *1_2string*
- *string1.2* should be *string1_2*

Comment: Is the `user` part of that always `user`? Is the `w` part always `w`?

Comment: Do you mean you need to replace a `.` enclosed with digits? `rawString.replaceAll("(\\d)\\.(\\d)","$1_$2");`?

Comment: Or if it's more specific to that `w#.##-user_request`: `String result = rawString.replaceAll("(w\\d)\\.(\\d+-user_request)", "$1_$2");`

Comment: What is the exact rule? How can the pattern be defined verbally?

Comment: See my first comment above - I think it must work for you.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/jdRXme

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot, it is working!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace a `.` enclosed with digits.

Use

```
rawString = rawString.replaceAll("(\\d)\\.(\\d)","$1_$2");
```

**Pattern details**:

- `(\\d)` - a digit captured into Group 1 (referred to via `$1` from the replacement pattern)
- `\\.` -  a literal dot
- `(\\d)`  - a digit captured into Group 2 (referred to via `$2` from the replacement pattern)

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/jdRXme):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("string1.2string", "string1.2", "1.2string");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(\\d)\\.(\\d)", "$1_$2"));
```

Output:

```
string1_2string
string1_2
1_2string
```